# remove css hover style

Tags: jquery, html, css, dhtml

I have mark up that toggles the hover css style using this rule.  When there's a checkbox inside the panel I want to remove the background image style.  Is this possible?  I've tried the following although it fails.

CSS:

```
   .StaffMode .day ul li.standard a:hover table {
        background:url("test.png"); 
    }
```

JS:

```
   $("li.test table li").hover(
        function () {
            if($(this).children(':checked')) {
              alert('need to remove the background image style');  // shows as expected
              $(this).children('a').removeClass('hover');  // this doesnt work?
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a real class that JavaScript can remove.

Comment: Can you post your HTML please or better a jsFiddle

Comment: i did try fiddle but its really complicated mark up so its quite hard to post anything meaningful.

Comment: im trying :hover although no joy. just seeing whats up with it.

Comment: is it possible using a firefox plugin to see what styles are being used when on hover?  I'm using firebug but its not quite showing what I need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you need to do is put some restriction on your `:hover` rule, and have your JavaScript change the element so it no longer applies. Something like this:

```
.has-hover:hover
{
    /* do whatever */
}
```

And then your JavaScript does this:

```
$(this).children('a').removeClass('has-hover');
```

You can't remove the `:hover` but you can remove the `has-hover` class, and since the rule requires both, this will prevent the `.has-hover:hover` rule from being applied.