# Highlight a td with mulitple div on hover, unhighlight on one of the divs

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, highlight

This is an extension to one of my previously asked questions. 
[CSS on hover effect on a <td> does not wok properly if <td> has multiple <div>s inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971600/css-on-hover-effect-on-a-td-does-not-wok-properly-if-td-has-multiple-divs#comment22772573_15971600)

I have a td with multiple divs inside below is the code

```
 <td>
  <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid red">left</div>
   <div style="display:inline-block">
   <div style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid blue">top left</div>
   <div id="imgMapDiv"style="display:inline-block; border:1px solid green">top right</div>
   <div>bottom </div>  
  </div>
</td>
```

This is my CSS

#MyTable td:hover {
  background: #cccccc;
}

What I want to achieve:
When my mouse enter the TD, the entire column should be highlighted - I have got this part.

However, when the mouse gets in the div with id imgMapDiv because that is a hyperlink, the entire TD should be unhighlighted. - This is the part, I am having problem with.

I have tried some jQuery way to toggle the class - but then once the TD looses the highlight class, it never comes back. I am looking for either a CSS only or a CSS javascript , jquery solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample:
Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/rP2sn/1/)
I updated it.
you'll have to modify this to your needs:

```
$("#imgMapDiv").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).parents('td').removeClass('someclass');
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).parents('td').addClass('someclass');
});
```

i use this [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747903/remove-css-hover-style).
i added a class to the `<td class="someclass">`
attach the hover to the class `td.someclass:hover { background: #cccccc; }`
and on `mouseenter()` i remove that class, and on `mouseleave()` i re-add it.

Comment: `when the mouse gets in the div with id imgMapDiv`, not just any `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

What jQuery ways you have tried? Have you tried jQuery's [mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) to set handlers for inner div? You can restore your TD's class on inner div's mouseleave() accessing it by [parents('td')](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: Thanks @Ezze for your reply. I didn't try mouseenter and mouseleave. Instead I tried inline css/js mouseover and mouseout events and toggling the class on these events. However, something was amiss because of which I couldn't get it working.